# How to login to the django testserver environment?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-testing

When I run the Django command:

```
./manage.py testserver
```

It creates a fresh database.

How can I login to the admin interface of that instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [pass the fixtures to the test server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#testserver-fixture-fixture). Just dump your desired userdata like this:

```
./manage.py dumpdata auth > users.json
```

and start your testserver like

```
./manage.py testserver users.json
```